# How to use Core Data at 3rd level View of navigation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Dear All, I am trying to build a navigation based iPhone application where I want to use Core Data modal at 3rd level view of navigation. The 1st and 2nd level view of this application are just simple tableViews. I have looked at the Apple CoreDataBooks application but there it used the methods for Core Data in the AppDelegate and RootViewController while I want to use these methods somewhere else. It is possible? Can somebody refer me to some tutorial for that? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Have your view controller create the Core Data stack.
2. Use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]` to find the app delegate from anywhere, and ask it for a context.
3. Pass your context as an argument down through the view controllers.

It's a choice only you can make, based on the ways you expect your application to change in the future.